# 1-dimensional FG-Modules

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose $V$ is a two-dimensional FG-Module and there exists $g,h \in G$ $v \in V$ such that $(gh).v \neq (hg).v$. Show that $V$ is irreducible.

I can understand the idea of this is to use Maschke's Theorem, which states if $U$ is a proper submodule of $V$, then there exists a proper submodule $W$ of $V$ such that $V=U \oplus W$. Now the only possibility for proper submodules is $dim(U)=dim(W)=1$, however given there exist elements which do not commute, I do not think this is possible. Can anyone clarify this for me please?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, if $V$ were reducible we could write $V = W \oplus U$ (I am assuming the characteristic of $F$ does not divide the order of $G$).

But now observe that the action of $G$ on $W \oplus U$ must factor through the abelianization of $G$. To see this, pick a basis $\{w\}$ for the 1-dimensional vector space $W$ and a basis $\{u\}$ for $U$. Then $G$ is acting by diagonal matrices, and these commute with one another.